# How to hide the password and secret key from karate log

Tags: karate

Just checking if there is any way we can hide the username password and secret key from karate log, which I am using to generate the bearer token.  Apology if this has already been answered[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#log-masking
You can use java code to mask the specific info. Refer above link for example.

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/699 This should be useful as well.

You can tweak your logback.xml file as well by changing the log level or completely disabling it. Above issue has info around that.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much. Updating logback xml file is an easy option.

Comment: Done, apology for the delay and thank you for helping me